# Why was this post closed

Tags: discussion, support, scope, closed-questions, flagging

https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/2168/most-popular-beer-by-country

I think this should be reopened as Community question as the only question Country wise to check for their respective specialities of beer brands

Answer (score 2):

@BeerFreezer. Thanks for participating in the meta as well as the main site.

As discussed elsewhere in the meta, the consensus at Beer.SE is, unlike other stack exchanges, to allow regional questions *as long as they are sufficiently constrained*. There are hundreds of countries that produce beer, and therefore, although I think it's indeed a useful question, I agreed (with whoever cast the first close vote) that the question was [too broad].

Take a look at this question: [What does AngularJS do better than jQuery? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414012/what-does-angularjs-do-better-than-jquery).

Try to remember that questions aren't closed because they're not useful, but rather because they don't fit certain site guidelines. Even if I don't personally agree with site guidelines (I'm actually closer to your side than you might think), as a moderator I am somewhat obligated to enforce the guidelines as set by the community. You'll still get reputation for upvotes of course—you just won't be seeing any new answers, since, it's been decreed the question covers too much ground and lacks specificity.

That said, you've reminded me of this question of mine: [Local beers to try at airports (major airports only)](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/580/local-beers-to-try-at-airports-major-airports-only). To give you some context, at the time, the site was very young and I was trying to increase community participation by asking a "fun" question—a question any of us might remember the next time we're at a brewery in an airport. Some users commented immediately that the question wasn't well-suited for an SE site; I shared their sentiments and agreed to a motion to close. However, one might argue users aren't willing to act "against" a moderator. (Though, personally, I don't see close votes as antagonistic, at all. Also, I try to respect users by believing in their willingness to express honest thoughts; similarly I hope I have users' respect in trusting me to be able to handle said thoughts.) Now, the above question, I attempted to "constrain" by defining a "minimum enplanements" threshold. However, since I'm also allowing 1 airport per country *regardless* off that criterion, clearly my question is even less constrained than yours! And especially since the site has grown and there's less of a need for the original purpose I sought to fulfill (fun, immediate participation), I will be consistent in my judgments and close my own question.

Please don't hesitate to speak up about things like this in the future.

If you still disagree with my judgment, that's okay! If you believe your question would be valid as a community wiki, then please find a meta.stackexchange.com post that helps substantiate your reasoning. (I'm placing the burden of proof on you, since the community has already voted according to its established system.)